# Next JS with Courtain.js library not receiving parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, curtains.js

Good day friends,

I am creating a website and in the homepage I need to insert an image that is distorted with an animation. For that I got a library called Courtain.js that cost me to understand and a developer managed to make it work and sent me this code, as a component of React.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import image from './images/1.png';
import {Curtains} from 'curtainsjs';
const planeParams = {
  vertexShaderID: "plane-vs", // our vertex shader ID
  fragmentShaderID: "plane-fs", // our framgent shader ID
  uniforms: {
    time: {
      name: "uTime", // uniform name that will be passed to our shaders
      type: "1f", // this means our uniform is a float
      value: 0,
    },
  }
};
class CurtainsPage extends React.Component {
  constructor( props ) {
    super(props);
    this._planes = null;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // if we got our curtains object, create the plane
    this.props.curtains && this.createPlanes(this.props.curtains);
  }

  componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    // if we haven't got our curtains object before but got it now, create the plane
    if(!this.props.curtains && nextProps.curtains) {
      this.createPlanes(nextProps.curtains);
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // remove the plane before unmounting component
    if(this.props.curtains && this._planes) {
      this.props.curtains.removePlane(this._planes);
      this._planes = null;
    }
  }
  createPlanes(curtains) {
    // create our plane
    if(curtains) {
      this._planes = curtains.addPlane(this.planeElement, planeParams);
      this._planes.onRender(function() {
        this.uniforms.time.value++;
      });

    }
  }
// register our plane element ref
  registerPlaneElement(el) {
    this.planeElement = el;
  }

  render() {

    return (
        <div
            className="curtain"
            ref={(el) => this.registerPlaneElement(el)}
        >
          <img src={image} alt={"image"}/>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
class App extends Component {

  constructor( props ) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      curtains: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let curtains = new Curtains("canvas");
    this.setState({ curtains: curtains });
  }

  render() {
    let curtains = this.state.curtains;
    console.log("start",curtains)
    return (
              <div className="App">
                    <div id="canvas" />
                    <CurtainsPage curtains={curtains}/>
              </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The problem is that the site I am developing with Next JS and this technology uses SSR and I think that is bringing me problems. The library function does not even recognize me the shaders that I am sending. Can someone help me with this? This is my code in Next JS.

```
import { Fragment, Component } from "react";
import Nav from "../components/Nav";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

import ArrowDownIcon from "@material-ui/icons/KeyboardArrowDown";

import "./index.scss";

import image from "./img/1.png";
import { Curtains } from "curtainsjs";

const planeParams = {
  vertexShaderID: "plane-vs", // our vertex shader ID
  fragmentShaderID: "plane-fs", // our framgent shader ID
  uniforms: {
    time: {
      name: "uTime", // uniform name that will be passed to our shaders
      type: "1f", // this means our uniform is a float
      value: 0
    }
  }
};

class CurtainsPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._planes = null;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // if we got our curtains object, create the plane
    this.props.curtains && this.createPlanes(this.props.curtains);
  }

  componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    // if we haven't got our curtains object before but got it now, create the plane
    if (!this.props.curtains && nextProps.curtains) {
      this.createPlanes(nextProps.curtains);
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // remove the plane before unmounting component
    if (this.props.curtains && this._planes) {
      this.props.curtains.removePlane(this._planes);
      this._planes = null;
    }
  }
  createPlanes(curtains) {
    // create our plane
    if (curtains) {
      this._planes = curtains.addPlane(this.planeElement, planeParams);
      this._planes.onRender(function() {
        this.uniforms.time.value++;
      });
    }
  }
  // register our plane element ref
  registerPlaneElement(el) {
    this.planeElement = el;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="curtain" ref={el => this.registerPlaneElement(el)}>
        <span>Hey</span>
        <img src={image} alt={"image"} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Index extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      curtains: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let curtains = new Curtains("canvas");
    this.setState({ curtains: curtains });
  }

  render() {
    let curt = null;

    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      let curtains = this.state.curtains;
      console.log("start", curtains);
      curt = <CurtainsPage curtains={curtains} />;
    }

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Nav />
        <div id="homesection">
          <div id="bigheader">
            <div id="canvas" />
            {curt}
          </div>
          <div className="sectionfooter">
            <div className="flexcenterall">
              <ArrowDownIcon className="marginbigright" />
              <span className="fuentesecundaria normal">
                Scroll down to continue
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="firstsection">
          <div id="firstcontent">Hey</div>
          <div className="sectionfooter">
            <div className="flexcenterall">
              <ArrowDownIcon className="marginbigright moradotext" />
              <span className="fuentesecundaria normal negrotext big">
                Where do you want to start?
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="secondsection">
          <div>
            <h2>MARKETING & COPYWRIGHTING</h2>
          </div>
          <div>Hola</div>
          <div>Hola</div>
          <div>Hola</div>
          <div>Hola</div>
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Index;
```

The image appears but does not distort, I think it is because the library is not receiving the parameters correctly or it is an SSR error. I am getting an error that vertex and shaders are not specified.

Answer (score 1):

instead of specifying your shaders as HTML ID strings, pass them directly as strings:

```js
const vertexShader = `
    precision mediump float;

    // default mandatory variables
    attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
    attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;

    uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
    uniform mat4 uPMatrix;

    // our texture matrix uniform
    // since no data-sampler attribute is specified on your <img /> tag
    // the texture matrix use the default lib name: "uTextureMatrix0"
    uniform mat4 uTextureMatrix0;

    // custom variables
    varying vec3 vVertexPosition;
    varying vec2 vTextureCoord;

    void main() {
        gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);

        // do what you need to do in your vertex shader here...

        // varyings
        vTextureCoord = (uTextureMatrix0* vec4(aTextureCoord, 0.0, 1.0)).xy;
        vVertexPosition = aVertexPosition;
    }
`;

const fragmentShader = `
    precision mediump float;

    varying vec3 vVertexPosition;
    varying vec2 vTextureCoord;

    // since no data-sampler attribute is specified on your <img /> tag
    // the sampler name use the default lib name: "uSampler0"
    uniform sampler2D uSampler0;

    void main() {
        // do what you need to do in your fragment shader...

        vec4 texture = texture2D(uSampler0, vTextureCoord);

        // draw our texture
        gl_FragColor = texture;
    }
`;

const planeParams = {
  vertexShader: vertexShader, // our vertex shader
  fragmentShader: fragmentShader, // our framgent shader
  uniforms: {
    time: {
      name: "uTime", // uniform name that will be passed to our shaders
      type: "1f", // this means our uniform is a float
      value: 0
    }
  }
};
```

That should solve your issue.